# Identifying this 6502 Assembler

Tags: commodore-64, assembly, 6502, identify-this-software

I found some 6502 assembler code for a Commodore 64 program that uses meta commands like `#include "foobar"`, define the address to be assembled to via `*=$1234` and define labels without a colon. Comments are marked with a leading `;`, and the syntax allows for specifying characters as constants such as in `lda #'A'`.

Which assembler programs have this kind of syntax and could be used to assemble the file?

I already know that

- `ca65` assembler uses keywords like `.import` and `.export` but not `#include`. And `ca65` requires a colon after a label definition
- `dasm` assembler files define the start address with the org directive, but not with `*=`
- `kickass` assembler has different comment format
- `64tass` does not know the `include`keyword

so it is none of the above (I tried and the build failed).

Comment: So far it might be safe to assume you're looking fro an 6502 assembler, but what computer?

Comment: It is for a C64, I added it to the description.

Comment: I suggest ignoring `#include` and any other C preprocessor like directive, and assume the source code you're looking at meant to handled by passing the source though a C preprocessor before being assembled.  The GNU Assembler doesn't support C preprocessing directives, but you'll find a lot of code written for it that uses them anyways.

Comment: Having used DASM extensively for 15 years, I 'converted' to KickAss a couple of years ago. It's my preferred cross-assembler for 6502 now, and well worth the effort of doing the work necessary to shift from DASM (or other) syntax.

Comment: Do you know anything about the age of the source? It could narrow down the possibilities. Also comments might give some clues to those who knows the assembler.

Comment: gcc can run a preprocessor-only pass on any file, not just C files. a friend of mine once used it as an improvised static site generator so he could add `#include "header.html"` to the top of all of his blog posts. (then he'd run it through the gcc preprocessor and push the final pages to his ftp)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it's [xa (xa65)](http://www.floodgap.com/retrotech/xa/):

- ☑ *`#include "foobar"`*
- ☑ *define the address to be assembled to via `*=$1234`*
- ☑ *define labels without a colon*
- ☑ *Comments are marked with a leading `;`*
- ☑ *specifying characters as constants such as in `lda #'A'`* — the example given in the manual uses double quotes (`lda #"A"`): is that a disqualifier?
- ☒ *`.pet` pseudo-op to include [PETSCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII)-encoded strings* — nope, sorry, but you might be able to replicate that in xa65 with `.asc` and running the assembler with the `-O PETSCII` option.

**Update**: via comments

> *narrator voice*: it was not xa65, but DreamAss ([original link](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=14608)|[newer github link](https://github.com/docbacardi/dreamass)).

Comment: I just had a chat with André Fachat, the original author, and he's pretty sure that xa65 makes a good match - including the single quote part, which he double checked in source. So I guess Scruss hit it.

Comment: I tried `xa` and it threw an error on a command ".pet". Googling that led me to the right assembler, it was [DreamAss](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=14608). Thanks a lot for the idea with `xa` helped me find it!

Comment: ah, you never mentioned the `.pet` bit. Glad you found your assembler, even if it has a truly terrible name …

Comment: @PeterB. what is `.pet`? For the Commodore PET? You said the source is for the C64?

Comment: @Wilson - `.pet` seems to be the directive in DreamAss to include the following bytes in [PETSCII ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII), which was common to most of the C= 8-bits

Comment: Exactly, `.pet` includes a follwing string in PETSCII encoding, so that those bytes can be directly copied to the screen memory. Sorry for not mentioning earlier that there was a `.pet` directive in the code, it did not come to my attention until recently because most of the assemblers failed much earlier and the code was extensively long.

Comment: the equivalent to `.pet` on xa65 might be `.asc` and then running the assembler with `-O PETSCII`